# Forcing AVX intrinsics to use SSE instructions instead

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, sse, avx

Unfortunately I have an AMD piledriver cpu, which seems to have problems with AVX instructions:

> Memory writes with the 256-bit AVX registers are exceptionally slow. The measured throughput is 5 - 6 times slower than on the previous model (Bulldozer), and 8 - 9 times slower than two 128-bit writes.

In my own experience, I've found mm256 intrinsics to be much slower than mm128, and I'm assuming it's because of the above reason.

I really want to code for the newest instruction set AVX though, while still being able to test builds on my machine at a reasonable speed. Is there a way to force mm256 intrinsics to use SSE instructions instead? I'm using VS 2015.

If there is no easy way, what about a hard way. Replace `<immintrin.h>` with a custom made header containing my own definitions for the intrinsics which can be coded to use SSE? Not sure how plausible this is, prefer easier way if possible before I go through that work.

Comment: I don't think there is. They're not going to overhaul their compiler for one specific processor. (Only Piledriver has that bug.)

Comment: You should give a reference when you quote something. And yes, there is a solution for this. Agner Fog's vector class.  Use a AVX vector such as `Vec8f` and compile with `-D__SSE4_2__ -D__XOP__`.

Comment: Are you using 256-bit is actually slower? Could you have an alignment issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Agner Fog's [Vector Class Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass) and add this to the command line in Visual Studio: `-D__SSE4_2__ -D__XOP__`.

Then use an AVX sized vector such as `Vec8f` for eight floats. When you compile without AVX enable it will use the file `vectorf256e.h` which emulates AVX with two SSE registers.  For example `Vec8f` inherits from `Vec256fe` which starts like this:

```
class Vec256fe {
protected:
    __m128 y0;                         // low half
    __m128 y1;                         // high half
```

If you compile with `/arch:AVX -D__XOP__` the VCL will instead use the file `vectorf256.h` and one AVX register.  Then your code works for AVX and SSE with only a compiler switch change.

If you don't want to use `XOP` don't use `-D__XOP__`.

---

As Peter Cordes pointed out in his answer, if you your goal is only to avoid 256-bit load/stores then you may still want VEX encoded instructions (though it's not clear this will make a difference except in some special cases).  You can do that with the vector class like this

```
Vec8f a;
Vec4f lo = a.get_low();  // a is a Vec8f type
Vec4f hi = a.get_high();
lo.store(&b[0]);         // b is a float array
hi.store(&b[4]);
```

then compile with `/arch:AVX -D__XOP__`.

Another option would be be one source file that uses `Vecnf` and then do

```
//foo.cpp
#include "vectorclass.h"
#if SIMDWIDTH == 4
typedef Vec4f Vecnf;
#else
typedef Vec8f Vecnf;
#endif
```

and compile like this

```
cl /O2 /DSIMDWIDTH=4                     foo.cpp /Fofoo_sse
cl /O2 /DSIMDWIDTH=4 /arch:AVX /D__XOP__ foo.cpp /Fofoo_avx128
cl /O2 /DSIMDWIDTH=8 /arch:AVX           foo.cpp /Fofoo_avx256
```

This would create three executables with one source file.  Instead of linking them you could just compile them with `/c` and them make a CPU dispatcher.  I used `XOP` with avx128 because I don't think there is a good reason to use avx128 except on AMD.

Comment: I wonder how could I do the opposite. Push `__m256` into `Vec8fe` in Vector Class Library. Yea, it doesn't make sense, but I need this case.

Comment: @Royii why do you need this case? If you have __m256 that mean you have compiled with AVX enabled and then the VCL will use `Vec8f` and not `Vec8fe`.

Comment: Because in some cases I'd like 2 different codes in my system. One for SSE and one for AVX. The problem with VCL it only handles one of them. I wish I could enforce it to use AVX with `Vec8f` and SSE with `Vec4f`.

Comment: @Royi, make a CPU dispatcher and choose the code path based on the instruction set. Using Vec8fe in some cases can give worse results than using Vec4f twice. I avoid the emulated types.

Comment: The problem I can't do it in my program. I have a function which is built with SSE Intrinsics only and the same function using AVX Intrinsics. It's not a compiler decision how to compile. I want it be written that way.

Comment: @Royi, ask a quesiton on SO. It's hard to understand the problem with these comments. A VCL + intrinsic question is interesting. I'm not the only one that uses the VCL so others could answer your question anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use SSE instructions.  What you want is for 256b stores to be done as two separate 128b stores, still with VEX-coded 128b instructions.  i.e. 128b AVX `vmovups`.

---

gcc has `-mavx256-split-unaligned-load` and `...-store` options (enabled as part of `-march=sandybridge` for example, presumably also for Bulldozer-family (`-march=bdver2` is piledriver).  That doesn't solve the problem when the compiler knows the memory *is* aligned, though.

---

You could override the normal 256b store intrinsic with a macro like

```
// maybe enable this for all BD family CPUs?

#if defined(__bdver2) | defined(PILEDRIVER) | defined(SPLIT_256b_STORES)
   #define _mm256_storeu_ps(addr, data) do{ \
      _mm_storeu_ps( ((float*)(addr)) + 0, _mm256_extractf128_ps((data),0)); \
      _mm_storeu_ps( ((float*)(addr)) + 4, _mm256_extractf128_ps((data),1)); \
   }while(0)
#endif
```

gcc defines `__bdver2` (Bulldozer version 2) for Piledriver (`-march=bdver2`).

You could do the same for (aligned) `_mm256_store_ps`, or just always use the unaligned intrinsic.

Compilers optimize the `_mm256_extractf128(data,0)` to a simple cast.  I.e. it should just compile to

```
vmovups       [rdi], xmm0         ; if data is in xmm0 and addr is in rdi
vextractf128  [rdi+16], xmm0, 1
```

However, [testing on godbolt shows that gcc and clang are dumb](http://goo.gl/upZD8m), and extract to a register and *then* store.  ICC correctly generates the two-instruction sequence.

Comment: Since on AMD AVX is basically emulated in hardware as SSE twice what's wrong with using the non-VEX encoded instructions? The only advantage I can think of use the AVX instructions but splitting the loads/stores is using fewer registers and less instructions in the instruction cache.

Comment: I guess since unaligned loads can't be folded for non-VEX encoded instructions that's one reason to use VEX encoded instructions.

Comment: @Zboson: yeah, according to what I've read (e.g. Agner Fog), on AMD there's usually little to no advantage in using 256b vectors.  128b vectors with VEX-coded instructions are usually the best bet.  This answer is useful to help develop / debug AVX software using a Piledriver machine for development.  You can use 256b intrinsics without stepping on the 256b-store performance bug.  So you'll get about equal speed on Piledriver to what you would if you'd written your code to use `_mm_*` 128b intrinsics, but hopefully much more speed on Intel HW.

Comment: what about stores that you can't manually code like register over flows, the compiler auto generates the store instructions. Can't change those can you?

Comment: @Volatile: no, you can't.  The correct term is "spill", not "overflow", to describe what the compiler does when it runs out of registers to hold all the local variables and temporaries.  (i.e. it "spills registers to the stack".)  IDK if it can assume that the stack is 32B-aligned, though, so `gcc -mavx256-split-unaligned-store` might still generate a 2-instruction store.  In most code, spills will be infrequent (e.g. a few times per call, not per loop iteration).  Since the problem you're trying to avoid is just a ~17 cycle perf problem, not a segfault, you're prob. ok.

Comment: Actually, does one 256b store jam up the store unit entirely, or can 128b and other smaller stores still execute while a one-per-17-clocks 256b store is in flight?

Comment: @Volatile: I just tested by writing a function that uses 17 `__m256` variables.  http://goo.gl/3cwpgz.  It uses them as accumulators for an FP sum, so the spill is inside the loop here.  gcc aligns the stack, then makes a stack frame.  Also, I just discovered that operators are overloaded for `__m256` variables in GNU C, so you can add them with `ymm0 += ymm1` to get a `vaddps` instruction.  (gcc/clang, but not icc13).  Also, gcc only does one `vxorps` and then uses `vmovaps` to zero the other regs, even with `-march=sandybridge` where `vxorps` runs 4/clock, `vmovaps r,r` 3/clock.